# Why do I get this error when I try to print something in Putty?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, ascii

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am downloading a website and then printing its contents...simple.
Do I have to encode it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utf-8 for start. Website you download might have different charset than ANSI and those extra characters can not be printed on console.

So in place where you do `print text` do `print text.encode('utf-8')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Putty configured to accept UTF-8 encoded data.

Answer (score 0):

`print`ing stuff to standard output can be problematic, because Python often doesn't know what character encoding the system is using. In the face of this Python 2 assumes the most conservative choice, US ASCII. So when you try to print a string that contains characters that aren't in ASCII, like the U+2019 smart quote `’`, it gives you this error.

In Python 3 the default charset guess for `sys.stdout.encoding` is UTF-8. If you are sure that your standard output (ie. PuTTY in your case) should accept UTF-8, then yes you can encode it explicitly:

```
print content.encode('UTF-8')
```